# Arranging a grade-table in a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I am giving a homework exercise that the student can submit in singles or pairs. The solutions are submitted in a Google form with three fields: submitter1, submitter2 (optional), solution. The submissions automatically go into a Google spreadsheet with four columns: submitter1, submitter2, solution, and grade (filled in by the TA). For example:

```
submitter1   submitter2   solution   grade
111          222          x          100
333                       y          90
444          555          z          80
```

I would like to create a second sheet that automatically lists the grades of each submitter alone, e.g:

```
submitter   grade
111         100
222         100
333         90
444         80
555         80
```

The order in the second table is not important.

Is there a way to do this in Google spreadsheet?

Alternatively, is there a way to do this in another spreadsheet software, such as LibreOffice Calc or Excel? (in that case I could copy the spreadsheet to that program and do the calculations there, though it is less convenient than doing it directly in Google spreadsheet).

EDIT: The main problem is to collect all submitter IDs into a single column. I do not know in advance how many submissions there will be, and how many of them will be single/pair. I tried to put in the "submitter" column:

```
 =IF(ISBLANK(Sheet1!A2),Sheet1!$B$2,Sheet1!A2)
```

and copy it downwards. This gives me all the first-submitters, and then the first second-submitter. But then how to automatically take the next second-submitters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List the submitters with this in A2,

```
=ArrayFormula(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(Sheet1!A2:B&CHAR(9)),CHAR(9)))))
```

Retrieve their grades with this formula,

```
=index(Sheet1!D:D, iferror(match(A2, Sheet1!A:A, 0), match(A2, Sheet1!B:B, 0)))
```

Linked google-sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WWN96AdYSx6ddArbBuGrDU_jCrO7WGTFA2Te1kaW-dw/edit?usp=sharing) (updated)

Answer (score 1):

```
=UNIQUE({{Sheet1!A:A,Sheet1!D:D};{Sheet1!B:B,Sheet1!D:D}})
```

[Arrange arrays](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276) and  do the formulas. QUERY to remove blanks, if needed:

```
=QUERY(UNIQUE({{Sheet1!A:A,Sheet1!D:D};{Sheet1!B:B,Sheet1!D:D}}),"Select Col1,Col2 Where Col1 is not null")
```